# Tagging subsites and contents within it for search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-metadata, tagging

Is it possible to tag (preferable automatic) subsites and content underneath it on creation?

My use-case is that I have 3 top level subsites:

- Subsite A tagged with `A`
- Subsite B tagged with `B`
- Subsite C tagged with `C`

and I do a search, I would like to refine by the tags so that I only get content found under that subsite.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box. Folks will tell you to use the Property Bag, that is a lame approach IMHO.

The easiest way to do this is to use a list and add the content to the list. Search will find the list item and then you can use a refiner based on the list...I really need to blog how to do this. Give me a few days.

Comment: That would be great. It's not just list items too. Basically anything under those main subsites: Pages, Documents, other subsites.

Comment: You said you want to "Tag a Site with A". That's what I can show you. Any other content you tag will already show in search. It's just sites (SPWeb objects) that you cannot tag.

Comment: Oh okay. Fair enough

Comment: As promised, I am starting to blog this solution. Be patient... :) http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2017/07/11/stop-using-the-property-bag/